# String interpolation cannot be recognized in visual studio when .net framework is set to 4.6.2

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, roslyn, c#-6.0

It is an asp.net website project with .net framework 4.6.2, and the C# language level is set to 6.0. While developing code in Visual Studio 2022, below code cannot be recognized.

`Console.WriteLine($"Hello {name}");`

Since string interpolation is a new feature introduced into C# 6, and the language level in our project is alreay set into C# 6, why is still not recognized by the syntax?

After, I run the command in Nuget console with `Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform -Version 3.6.0`, the problem is gone.

Why is it not working with C# 6 previously? What does `DotNetCompilerPlatform` do to make it work?

Comment: Do you also see this with .NET Framework 4.6? I created a .NET Framework 4.6 project and set the C# language version to 6 and I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yes, the .NET Framework is 4.6.2. It is only a website project, not web application.

Comment: Well, I only have .NET Framework 4.6 (.0) to test with, not 4.6.2 so I'll install 4.6.2 to see if I can reproduce it there.

Comment: I can't reproduce with .NET Framework 4.6.2 either. Why are you explicitly setting the language version to 6 rather than just using the latest?

Comment: Is this an error that shows up when editing code in Visual Studio, or is it a compiler error when you try to actually build your code? ...though mine builds and runs with these conditions without issue.

Comment: Hi @ProgrammingLlama, becasue we only have .net framework 4.6.2 in the windows server. And the maxminum c# laungage it supports is C#6, so we set it there. It is an error while editing the code.

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce it in Visual Studio 2022. Do you have any extensions installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I get it, and share it with you who may also encouter the same issue.

.Net Framework 4.6.2 already supports C# 6 syntax, including string interpolation.

If it is a console application, by default, it will use the compier(Roslyn) of .Net Framework 4.6.2, who already supports C# 6. Everything is fine. But if it is a asp.net website project, because the C# code is not compiled in VisualStudio, instead, it will be compiled in IIS when it receives the first http request. By default, IIS will not use  Roslyn to compile the website. So, we need to tell IIS to use the specific compiler to support C#6. This is why we have to  run below command

`Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform -Version 3.6.0`

While we are writing asp.net website C# code in Viusal Studio, it may also have similar mechanism so it shows red wave line to tell there is error.